# How can a predictor be significant, only on the presence of non-significant ones?

Tags: regression

I am performing  **longitudinal mixed modelling**. What does it mean when a regressor (predictor) alone is not significant for the model (P>0.05) but when I add another predictor, which turns out to be non-significant, the first one is suddenly significant?: e.g.

In the following model age is not significant

`Test_performance ~ age + sex, random=(~1 | subjects)`

But when I add another variable (e.g. brain size), age is suddenly significant, event though brain size is not.

How is this possible and what does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

This is usually due to multicollinearity.  The whole point of the null is that it is the true model.  You can't add a variable or your significance tests are meaningless.  You should have performed a correction if you were going to continually add variables until you found significance.   Most likely the two predictors are highly correlated.

Comment: One question: Do you mean it is a wrongful approach to create several models with an increasing amount of variables?

Comment: The fact that the variables can be correlated means that the inclusion of one lessens the importance of one.  This is a variable selection issue.  Systematic procedures for comparing models such as step-wise selection are often used.  Then selection criteria such as Akaike's information criterion are used to pick the final model.

Comment: I think user25459 is saying exactly that @CoffeSurfer.  Including too many variables can hurt the accuracy of prediction.

Comment: This is a FAQ.  Although collinearity is a possible explanation, it's not the only one.

Comment: it should be noted that step-wise procedures can be highly biased. You would be better off reading a bit about variable selection procedures before continuing